# grouping data and showing it

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Table 1: Profiles

```
id
name
url
```

Table 2: Products

```
id
name
profileid (Reference Key, Profiles.id)
```

Now, tables have following data

Table 1: Profiles

```
id     name     url
-----------------------------
1      aaa      http://a.com
2      bbb      http://b.com
3      ccc      http://c.com
```

Table 2:

```
id     name     profileid
-----------------------------
1      mmm      1
2      nnn      1
3      ooo      2
```

Now I need **output as**

```
profileid     profilename     productname
------------------------------------------
1              aaa               mmm
                                 nnn
2              bbb               ---
3              ccc               ---
```

I know that left-join will do the trick, but it repeats the profile name. Is there any way to get profile id and name single time, and list of all associated products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P1.id AS profileid
     , P1.name AS profilename
     , GROUP_CONCAT(P2.productname)
  FROM Profiles AS P1 
  LEFT
  JOIN Products AS P2 
    ON P1.id = P2.profileid 
 GROUP 
    BY P1.id
     , P1.name 
 ORDER 
    BY profileid ASC
```